# can single point of failure in Hadoop can be addressed by integrating Zookeeper?

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper

I am looking for addressing the issue  of single point failure by integrating Zookeeper and allow Hadoop to use the namespace from Zookeeper? Is it possible? how can we address this
?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it might be technically possible, but this is not something that has been implemented in any shape or form just yet. You can't just plug it into ZooKeeper... it'll take some engineering effort to get it done (by you perhaps?!).

Here are a couple pointers to solutions of this:

- [AvatarNode](http://hadoopblog.blogspot.com/2010/02/hadoop-namenode-high-availability.html)
- [MapR](http://www.mapr.com/products/why-mapr/dependable) (commercial software)
- [A high-availability NameNode has been in the works and might end up soon in a future release](http://www.slideshare.net/cloudera/hadoop-world-2011-hdfs-name-node-high-availablity-aaron-myers-cloudera-sanjay-radia-hortonworks)

Comment: HI, thanks for the link.. since  this issue is addressed in different ways, what would you think the positive side of doing this integration ??

Answer (score 0):

That would not work very well. Cost of write in Zookeeper is high. The more nodes you have in ZK cluster the higher the cost. ZK keeps all the data in memory on all nodes. Namenode is on the contrary write focused component, especially if you talking about Hadoop, which is super write heavy.

Comment: Thanks for your input.. can you point to an article that explains this issue in detail??

Comment: Sorry, dont't have an article at hand. Zookeper info is available at their website, same with Hadoop Namenode. 
By the way, Hadoop Namenode problem is a bit exaggerated, until you have tenths or handreds of DFS nodes, you will just fine. Yes, there is still a SPOF, but cost of recovery is low. 
I also suggest you take a look at Hadoop.23 (NEXT), it does not solve reliability but does solve a lot of other operational issues. It also lay ground to solve reliability in next releases. I think - this is a way to go.